# How to set offline a User in the DB when it closes the browser?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i have a logout function that sets the User offline in my DB (mysql), but if it just closes the browser, in my DB the User is still online despite it's not , How can i manage this? How can i set the User Offline without press the logout botton? Cheers in advance !

Ps: Yes, i'm using SESSION

Comment: You can have a background task which periodically checks for the user's last activity and sets the user as offline after some time has passed, assuming you track the user's last activity.  But there's no way to detect what you're trying to detect.  Why do you need to "set a user as offline" anyway?  What are you actually tracking in the data?

Comment: On top of what David said, you could also have a JavaScript listener listen for the unload event: window.addEventListener("unload", function(e) { // AJAX call here })); You could do an AJAX call to logout the user on the server side. Please note that the unload event will also be fired when you click a link to another site, not only when you close the tab/browser.

Comment: @Ruben - I believe unload is fired if you you click a link to the site you are on, basically anytime the page is changed.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yes, I think it fires when you click any link.

Comment: Amending my previous statement... There's no *reliable* way to detect what you're trying to detect.  I still suspect that your best bet is to re-think what you're trying to do in the first place and what the actual needs of the system are.

Comment: @David - it can be reliably tracked using an interval with an ajax call to the server that saves the current time for that user in a database table, no page = no ajax call = no time updated.  Performance wise it's not ideal, but it's the only way to accurately do it.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: I'd even opt for tracking requests server-side instead, saving on the AJAX polling.  Basically tracking "last known activity" instead of "is user online".

Comment: @David - right but that largely depends on how often a page is reloaded, if you have content heavy pages then page reloads may be infrequent.  It also depends on how often and accurate the information needs to be.  I've done it before using session_set_save_handler ( handle the sessions myself ) and via ajax polling, just depends.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: True.  There are certainly options with pros and cons either way.  I think the best way to help the OP would be to have a better understanding of the underlying need here.  The specific thing the OP is asking is commonly asked, but very uncommonly actually needed.  Hopefully what's been presented here in comments and answers will be helpful, but I think there exists a good chance that it's a band-aid without actually solving the problem unless we know more.

Comment: @David - well said, it takes a good fundamental knowledge of how the internet works to understand how requests and state are done, to really understand why the browser cant tell the server this information.

Comment: Guys i've a website with a login page, i just want to know which user is online and which not.

Answer (score 1):

HI the only reliable way is to set an interval that calls the server and logs it in a database

```
 var timeout = 15000; //milliseconds
 setInterval( function(){
       $.post('yoursite/keepalive' ); 
 }, timeout );
```

Then you check the session on the server side you need a simple database table with the user id and a timestamp of the last time keepalive was called, then you just get the current time an there id ( from the session ) and save that.  Then you can check if its been more then say like `20` seconds you will know they are gone ( should be updated every 15 sec ).  Obviously you would need to have this interval on every page of your site to accurately track a user.

Things such as checking the session time, and unload are not accurate enough,

Unload is fired when any page is closed, so for example,
we have a user that has 2 pages open, they close one of them.  the other page is already loaded so there is no traffic between client and server, and no way to know that page is still open

for Session time we have a similar problem, say someone is reading a long post on your page,  They need to use the facilities and leave the page open.  30 minutes go by the come back and continue reading the post for another 10 minutes. now maybe the session has expired maybe it hasn't the fact remains they are still looking at your site, and you have no way to know it.

An interval will continue as long as the page is open and there are no javascript issues.  A disadvantage of this is it will also keep their session updated ( you can get around this by sending the user id along with the ajax and not using the session, but that has other complications ) because you have that 15 second update you can check anytime if it has been more then 15 seconds.  Say you want to display a list of online users to your other forum users, you just query for everyone with a current timestamp from that table, easy beazy.

As for the amount of time for the interval, you have to strike a balance between performance ( network traffic ) and how granular you need to know the information, if it's ok to only know if they logged off within the last minute then use that, if you can wait 5 minutes to know etc....

Really the Crux of the problem is how the server, and a client communicate.  Right there is no two way communication like if your on the phone. It's more like a walkies talky where you have to say 10-4 and let go of the button for the other guy to talk.  Essentially a client will make a request, that request is fulfilled by the server.  that is the end of the communication and the state.  Subsequent request state is maintained by using session so the next request uses that session to 'remember' the client. other then that there is no communication between client and server.  There is no way to know they hung up the phone, for example, but to ask them if they are still there. ( this is an oversimplification because you cant send a request from the server to ask, more like they have to tell you they are not there, unless you use node.js  or something like that ).

As @David has mentioned you could track this based on last activity, for that you would just need to know when the session was last updated.  One of the easiest ways is to move the session into a database handler via  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php  that way you can access when they were last active.

Using this vs ajax really depends on what you need to know, and how accurately.  There is also the content of your page to weigh in.  If you have a site that makes requests frequently it would be a better approach because you save on network traffic, for example.  However, if you have long post someone could be reading for 20-30 minutes but want to know more frequent then that use ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in  following ways.
1) send the Ajax request to server every 5 seconds to update the current time.
2) and where you want to show offline just get records where current time is more than 5 seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in many ways:

- Launch an [AJAX call on `onbeforeunload` javascript event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp). Prompting for a confirmation "Windows is closing, are you sure? YES/NO" should give you enough time to set the flag in the db, just be sure that if the user clicks "NO" you should unset your flag
- Check session time... Add a var in your `PHP_SESSION` that is updated at every user event. If it becomes older than a preset threshold (i.e. 5 minutes), you can safely assume the user is gone

Example for `onbeforeunload`

```
function myConfirmation() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to quit?';
}

window.onbeforeunload = myConfirmation;
```

Comment: actually the only reliable way is to have an ajax timer that updates something, unload is a pain because you'll have no way to know if they stay on your site after unload, for example they have another page open and close a second page.   without reloading that other page you have no way to know its open.  session time wont tell you if they are sitting there looking at a static page or if they have left. So really the only thing you can do is have an interval that updates a database record, and if it hasn't been updated for that interval then they probably have left, on every page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the javascript `beforeunload` event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // Some AJAX request to logout.php or whatever script handles the logout
}
```

It will trigger when the user attempts to close the current window.

Watch out though, even if the user closes a single tab (your page), the event will be triggered, so if there are other tabs opened, so the browser will be, and you'll still get your users logged out.

Also, if several tabs of your website are opened, and you close one of them, you'll get your users logged out, which may not be what you want, so you'll probably have to find a way around to fix it.